# Fancybox Jquery - Pass variable to iframe (

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the right way to pass and retrieve variables through Jquery. It's fairly straight forward I guess, though I just don't know how to construct the logic.

Base.html:

```
// Open Lightbox iframe Function
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
});
});

<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" 
   href="iframe.html" id= "1" 
   name="paul" 
   height="180cm" 
   brothers="2"> Show Iframe </a>
```

Then in my iframe.html I would like to retrieve and echo / print these assets.

e.g.

```
<p>Table id is: $id</p>
<p>The Person name is: $name </p>
<p>Their height is: $height  </p>
<p>The number of brothers they have is: $brother </p>
```

Comment: We need more information, we don't have enough to answer your question.

Comment: You don't have to repeat a question to get a faster answer. Please elaborate on the first one so people can help you.